# Add body class if class ".loading" active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the lazyload for a project, it loads images progressively.

https://github.com/verlok/lazyload

When the images are loading, the "loading" class is activated in the `<img class = "loading"> ... </ img>`

and when it finishes loading, the "loading" class is replaced by the class "loaded"

I want to know if it would be possible to add a class to a div based on the activity of the "loading" class.

I made a rather rustic example, just to demonstrate my goal.

```
if ($('img').hasClass('loading')) { 
$("body").addClass("images-is-loading"); 
$(".post-thumbnail").addClass("post-images-is-loading"); 
}
```

Could someone clarify me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to continuously check for the condition on regular intervals using `setInterval` . Here is the sample code:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if ($("img.loading").length) {//Checks if there is such element
    $("body").addClass("images-is-loading");
    $(".post-thumbnail").addClass("post-images-is-loading");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("images-is-loading");
    $(".post-thumbnail").removeClass("post-images-is-loading");
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is wonderful. It worked! But now I have another problem. Is it possible to remove the class after the other "loading" class is no longer active? I tried it here and it did not work, I also tested it with toggleClass but it stays in a loop, activating and deactivating. I need the class I add only to be active while the "loading" class is also active.

Comment: I begin to understand something. I'm using wordpress, and I have a page listing 10 posts with images. In this case, the "loading" class is being added and removed in each post when the image is loaded. I need the same to happen in my situation. As long as the "loading" class is active, then my class in the body will also be.

Comment: @JohnQuimera You can put the code to remove the class in the else case. Check updated code.

Comment: I've tried it that way. But it did not work. The class does not remove.I am using this example lazyload: http://www.andreaverlicchi.eu/lazyload/demos/simple.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any framework like Angular, data binding takes care of continuously checking the classes being added or deleted.
In other case, you have to use "setInterval" function of JavaScript.
ex:

```
setInterval (function () {
   // Your Code...
}, some frequency of time)
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval isnt great for this in my opinion, maybe it is better to look for the build in callback events like:

```
var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
elements_selector: ".lazy",
class_loading: "loading-img", 
callback_enter: function(el) {
  $(body).addClass('loading');
},
callback_loaded: function(el) {
  $(body).removeClass('loading');
}
```

});